# Choose colours by hex code when filling unbounded areas in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, color, hex

I am trying to use the 'fill bounded areas' feature in Inkscape, but it only appears to let me choose from the pre-configured colour selection. How do I specify exactly which colour I want using a HEX code? I can't use the 'fill and stroke' detail as I am not colouring an individual object. I have used other objects to create the shapes I want and am trying to fill those areas that make up those shapes with different colours. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bucket tool just creates path objects that can be edited like any other paths. Just make a filled shape with it and *then* change the color in the 'Fill and Stroke' panel with the new object selected.

By default the new object style for the bucket tool is set to 'Last used style', so once you set a color for one object, it will remember it for the next one until you change it again.